# Uniqueness of Roots of Normal Abelian Divisible Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $n\in \mathbb{N} $ and $g\in G$.
A solution $x\in G$ of $x^n =g$ is called $n^{th}$ root of g.
In addition, if every $g\in G$ has an $n^{th}$ root, then $G$ is called divisible.

If $H$ is a normal abelian divisible subgroup of a group $G$.
Must root of every $g\in H$ be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $G=H=$ multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers, and conssider $n$-th roots of $1$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.
Then if I consider torsion free group $G$, then it should be unique in this case is it?

Comment: Yes, in torsion-free abelian groups you get uniqueness of roots.